# active admin and inner joins

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activeadmin

In Active Admin (RoR), I'm getting data from a table, no problem with that.
But I want to add a sidebar with information thats related with an inner join.
But I don't know how to do this.

This my code:

```
ActiveAdmin.register Project do
   show do |project|
   ... works ...
   end
end

sidebar "Resources for this project", :only => :show do
  table_for project.project_resources.where('project_id = ?', project.id) do |row|
     column "Resource", Resource.where('id = ?', :resource_id) do |resource|
      :resource_name
    end
  end
end
```

As you can see, I'm trying to get the resource_name from resources-table. There is a 3th table, project_resource and this contains all the resource_ids for a project_id.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, this is the answer I was looking for:

```
sidebar "Resources for this project", :only => :show do
  table_for project.resources do |resource|
    column :resource_name do |row|
      link_to row.resource_name, admin_resource_path(row)
    end
  end
end
```